# How to write an application that uses the terminal as GUI? (in C)

Tags: c, user-interface, terminal

I'd like to write an application (in C) that uses the terminal of a *nix OS as its GUI. I mean an application of the kinds of emacs, vi etc. that take up the whole terminal window and jump back to the input prompt after quitting.
How would you go about doing that, preferably in C? Can someone point me to a tutorial covering that?

Comment: you can use [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) for that.

Comment: You could look at the [ncurses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Sounds like you want the [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use ncurses:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses 
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

It is available on all major distros.

Answer (score 4):

Well, actually this is not GUI (graphic user interface) but a text based interface. You can use the library [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) to create such applications in C.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library like `ncurses`, it is specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing in alternate solutions so that this question thread does not look so monotonic:

- the *slang* library (*mc* uses it, for example)